# Facing issue while using zoom feature for Map having nodes and Text

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get the zooming feature to work for a map having nodes and states' text. I am using below link for zooming:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2206340

[image]

When I am applying the logic from the link then the map is zooming with nodes and links but states' text is not zooming and after a few seconds the nodes and links also stop zooming, only the map zooms in and out. Below is my sample code which is based on D3 v4.

```
    // projection definition
var projection = d3.geoAlbers()
    .scale(width)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);



// path generator definition for major cities, including point radius
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection)
    .pointRadius(2);

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([height, 8 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select(this.domNode).append("svg")
      .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      /*.call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}))*/

      //.attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left +"," +margin.top+")")
      .on("click", function(d) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('nodes')) {
            me.clearSelections();
            me.endSelections();
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
     })
;


var g = svg.append("g")
    .call(zoom);

.....................
..................

.................
....................

function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
  g.selectAll("circle").attr("d", node); //I tried this and below for testing but it didn't work
  g.selectAll("line").attr("d", link);


}
```

Comment: I am Using V4 in my code. i.e https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js

Comment: can you make fiddle from your code?

Comment: I can't able to make fiddle because I am using d3 in some other technology and that is not going to work in the fiddle.If you ask any question for clarification then I can clarify you.

Comment: I am able to get work the nodes, links and states name zoom in and out by putting: selectAll() for node and link with there longitude and latitude locations and for states:
g.selectAll(".place-label").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
   ;

Comment: Hi @bumbeishvili  I have one issue that when I am using it with V4 then it is not working.Do I need to change something for V4?

Comment: yes, many things changed from v3 to v4.
for example   `d3.behavior.zoom()` changed to `d3.zoom()` , it will be easier if you find examples on v4 or your change d3 version to v3 (first variant is better).

Comment: @bumbeishvili I have used all other code with V4 so I can't change it to v3.I searched for v4 and I found https://bl.ocks.org/iamkevinv/0a24e9126cd2fa6b283c6f2d774b69a2 link which is having zooming feature but when I am applying it, my nodes, states sizes are not resizing accordingly(it remain big).Can you help me on this by giving an idea what should I have to change in the code which for V3 or what should I have to add in v4 code so that my nodes and text will adjust his size?

Comment: Can I include both versions in my code.Will it work?

Comment: I am not sure including both version is a good idea

Comment: @bumbeishvili can you help me on this.I am not having any idea how to do this in V4.

Comment: I can't, it requires more time, than I have

Comment: Can any one help me on this? I am stuck in this.Please help me.